# Как задать стиль кнопки внутри блока?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Почему-то, я не могу задать стиль для кнопки `<div id="but1">` и для текста в ней, она автоматически берет стиль с `<ul class="list">`. Как решить эту проблему? Уже замучился.. Спасибо!

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="list">

      <li class="item"><span class="cross">Текст</span>
        <div class="hid">   
            <div class="dr">
                <img src="/images/otzv.jpg" width="270" height="165"/>
            </div>              

            <div class="blok">Текст2                            
                <div id="but1">
                    <a href="/index"><div><span>Подробнее</span></div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы привели пример html кода, а где css? проверьте, что вы точно устанавливаете стили для кнопки т.е. правило должно быть типа `#but1{ display:block; border:1px red solid;}` например

Comment: Так нет, в том то и дело, что я использую как Вы написали и стиль устанавливается, но поверх стиля <ul class="list">. Т.е. кнопка выглядит как список <ul class="list"> + тот стиль, что я пропишу.

Comment: проблема решена.. всё было в <span> (<a href="/index"><div><span>Подробнее</span></div></a>).. как только переименовал в <spans> и создал стиль именно для <spans> так все заработало.. видимо стиль для <span> класса list всё портило. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

что то вы с `div` переборщили, используйте для кнопки `button`

Comment: проблема решена.. всё было в <span> (<a href="/index"><div><span>Подробнее</span></div></a>).. как только переименовал в <spans> и создал стиль именно для <spans> так все заработало.. видимо стиль для <span> класса list всё портило. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
.blok > #but1 {
    /* здесь ваши стили */ 
}
```

Можно также использовать костыль `!important`, но это не лучший вариант

Comment: Вообще без изменений.. но проблема в том, что даже используя стили вот так: #but1{ display:block; border:1px red solid;}, то кнопка выглядит как список <ul class="list"> + тот стиль, что я пропишу.

Comment: проблема решена.. всё было в <span> (<a href="/index"><div><span>Подробнее</span></div></a>).. как только переименовал в <spans> и создал стиль именно для <spans> так все заработало.. видимо стиль для <span> класса list всё портило. Спасибо за помощь!